# C# DataTable update Access Database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datatable, oledb

How can I save a `DataTable` to a file. accdb (Access) existing one? I've used the following code and it does not work:

```
using (OleDbConnection oledbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connection))
{
   oledbConnection.Open();
   string query = "SELECT * FROM Student";
   using (OleDbCommand oledbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, oledbConnection))
   {
      using (OleDbDataAdapter oledbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oledbCommand))
      {
         using (OleDbCommandBuilder oledbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbDataAdapter))
         {
            oledbDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
            oledbDataAdapter.InsertCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
            oledbDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            oledbDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
         }
      }
   }
   oledbConnection.Close();
}
```

The variable dataTable is initialized with the original contents of the file, then it was modified by adding a row and now I have to update the table in the database.

I tried using the following code, but that does not work :(

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Student", connection);
OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
da.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
// create and insert row in the DataTable
da.Update(dataTable);
```

Comment: If you issue `dataTable.GetChanges()` in the `Watch Window`, do you get any changes?

Comment: This method was useful for another function, but not for this. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have made some changes in the datatable, then you could pass the generated update/insert/delete command to the adapter in this way

```
oledbDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
oledbDataAdapter.InsertCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
oledbDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = oledbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
oledbDataAdapter.Update(datatable);
```

Now the adapter knows how to update your table

Comment: Good catch Steve, I missed the fact that the OP wasn't assigning the commands when I read the `GetDeleteCommand()` lines!

Comment: yes! "Can not add the amount of data you want. field too small. inserting or pasting less data."

Comment: Well, that's another problem. It is generated by the value inserted in one of your table's column. The size of this (probably text column) is not enough to contain the data typed in your input boxes by your user (need to trim it down or set a maxlength)

Comment: I suggest to post a new question, It will get more attention than a comment in this answer.